# Integer construction variations

Tags: java, integer

Hey all, I ran into an interesting occurrence and am looking for an explanation.

In Java 1.6:

```
Integer a = new Integer(5);
Integer b = new Integer(5);

System.out.println(a == b);

Integer c = 5;
Integer d = 5;

System.out.println(c == d);
```

I get:

```
false
true
```

In Eclipse I checked in the debugger. `a` and `b` are different objects, while `c` and `d` are the same objects (but different from `a` and `b`).

Can anyone clue me in on what's going on under the hood? Is this JVM magic? Realizing that a Integer(5) is already on the stack?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java caches `Integer` instances for values it deems close enough to zero if they're constants. Manually creating an `Integer` using `new` bypasses that cache. You can call `Integer.valueOf` with an `int` to get the corresponding `Integer` without bypassing the cache.

You may want to search for "JVM Integer cache" on your search engine of choice for more information.

Comment: I believe all values from -128 to 127 are cached, and i'm pretty sure it was for Sun's JVM.

Comment: See also [`Integer.valueOf(int i)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29)

Comment: in addition, the jvm is allowed to cache integers fetched thru Integer.valueOf, so you may get the same object back for two calls to Integer.valueOf even if the number is outside the -128-127 range.

Comment: Interesting related read, http://thecodersbreakfast.net/index.php?post/2011/04/13/Java-Quiz-44

Comment: Huh. That is fancy. I figured `new` forced the object creation but was confused as to how Java/JVM resolved the other instances. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

@icktoofay's answer nails it, but the comments are muddying the waters.

- The JLS edition 3.0 *requires* that integers in the ranges -128 to +127 are autoboxed to cached values;  see [JLS section 5.1.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.7).  In other words, you can rely on this behaviour for integers in that range, for all complaint Java 5 and later platforms.

  (Similar requirements apply to booleans, bytes, chars and shorts.)
- The JLS specifically *allows* the same autoboxing behaviour to extend across a wider range of values.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was aware of the autoboxing, but didn't realize that cached values were implicated. Very neat little thing.