# Why is == true for some Integer objects?

Tags: java, integer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integer wrapper objects share the same instances only within the value 127?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117132/integer-wrapper-objects-share-the-same-instances-only-within-the-value-127)

I have copied the following program snippet from the Khalid Mughal SCJP, but I am unable to
understand the output.

```
 public class RQ200_60 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i = -10;
        Integer j = -10;
        System.out.print(i==j);         // output: true -- why true?
        System.out.print(i.equals(j));  // output: true
        Integer n = 128;
        Integer m = 128;
        System.out.print(n==m);         // output: false
        System.out.print(n.equals(m));  // output: true
    }
}
```

The above program giving output true for the first print statement but it supposed to give false because it is reference comparison with == relational operator. But third print gives false and I don't understand this inconsistency.

Explanations are greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309640/compare-two-integer , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581913/wrapper-class-and-operator , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117132/wrapper-objects-share-the-same-address-space-only-within-the-value-127 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865056/integer-construction-variations

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In the first case, both the objects `i` and `j` are pointing to the same cached object. By default, the range between -128 and 127 are cached as `Integer` Object. We can increase the range using [`JVM arguments`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6199312/571189)

Comment: +1 Interesting, didn't know that was configurable.

Comment: I also didn't know it's configurable. Autoboxed values from -128 to 127 *must* be identity-equal according to [JLS 5.1.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.7)

Answer (score 13):

The answers about caching are correct. However, if you go...

```
Integer i = new Integer(10);
Integer j = new Integer(10);
```

...then you avoid the caching and the results will be what you expected.

Comment: @pst thanks for the edit.  Typing on my Nook is a bit awkward.

Answer (score 8):

Integer objects *may* be cached for the ones that represent a value close to 0. (The specification for the implementation may tell you some details). This is presumably to save memory (values close to 0 are common, and it would waste a lot of memory to make a new object for every variable with the same value).

`==` checks whether two things are the same object; you **may or may not** have the same Integer object for any two given variables with the same value. You are not supposed to check with `==` because you are **not supposed to care** whether it is the same object; it is the value of an `Integer` that matters, not its identity.

Answer (score 1):

Here in this case the `Integer i` and `Integer j` holding the integer values which are in range of integer, range of an `Integer` is `-128 to 128`, and `Integer n` and `Integer m` exceeds the range of `Integer`