# Different integer values

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is == true for some Integer objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427416/why-is-true-for-some-integer-objects)

I have code fragment

```
Integer i1 = new Integer(a);
Integer i2 = new Integer(b);
if (i1 == i2)
{
// ...
}
```

When 'a' and 'b' are small numbers (e.g. 0-20) then i1 == i2 return true.
 But when 'a' and 'b' are great then i1 == i2 rerun false!
I don't understand, how can it be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read more about pool of integer values.
If 'a' and 'b' are between -127 and 128 then i1 == i2 return true
else i1 == i2 return false
Better use method .equals comparison.
if (i1.equals(i2))
{
}

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind you're using an Object and not a datatype.  Integer has an equals method which is defined as:

> Compares this object to the specified object. The result is true if
>   and only if the argument is not null and is an Integer object that
>   contains the same int value as this object.

You'll typically want to use the equals method for checking equality of Objects.

The quote is from:
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals(java.lang.Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)