# Wrong output for integer comparison values

Tags: java, comparison, integer, int

I have the following code.

```
public static void doIntCompareProcess() {
    int a = 100;
    int b = 100;

    Integer c = 200;
    Integer d = 200;

    int f = 20000;
    int e = 20000;

    System.out.println(c == d);
    compareInt(e, f);
    compareInt(a, b);
}

public static void compareInt(Integer v1, Integer v2) {
    System.out.println(v1 == v2);
}
```

That gives me this output:

```
false
false
true
```

Where the currect output should be:

```
false
false
false
```

Why am I getting the wrong output for the code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The last line corresponds to:

```
compareInt(100, 100);
```

Since `compareInt()` takes two `Integer` objects, the two parameters get auto-boxed. During that process, instances of `Integer(n)` *for small values of `n`* get interned. In other words, `compareInt()` receives *two references to the same `Integer(100)` object*. This is what's causing the last comparison to evaluate to `true`.

See [Using == operator in Java to compare wrapper objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149959/using-operator-in-java-to-compare-wrapper-objects)

The bottom line is to not use the `==` operator for directly comparing `Integer` objects. For further discussion, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1515811/367273

Comment: But the parameter is `Integer` class

Comment: This is a tricky bit, and it's surprising how often we forget about it. Great answer!

Answer (score 4):

Integer values in the primitive byte range -128 to 127 are cached for performance reasons. Since 100 is a value in this range, same object from the cache is returned everytime. For values not in this range are believed to be not required frequently and new Integer object is returned for them. Now in your case, you are comparing the object references and not the values and since 100 is coming from the cache, the arguments in compareInt() are pointing to the same object and hence the comparison equates to true.