# Primitive wrappers comparison

Tags: java, scjp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using == operator in Java to compare wrapper objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149959/using-operator-in-java-to-compare-wrapper-objects)

**java version 1.6.0_26**

**From a book** for SCJP exam preparation:

*In order to save memory, two instance of the following[Short and Integer from -128 and 127, and some other but doesn't matter for question] wrapper objects (created throught boixng), will always be == when their primitive values are the same.*

**What I did:**

If we will compare two integer from -128 to 127 like this:

```
1. Integer i1 = 10;
2. Integer i2 = 10;
3. System.out.println(i1 == i2); // true
```

But why the same give us "false" or may be it's not the same things:

```
4. Integer i3 = new Integer(10);
5. Integer i4 = new Integer(10);
6. System.out.println(i3 == i4); // false
```

My questions:

1) Does on the 1st line of code we make implicit boxing?

2) Why the 3rd and 6th lines of code give us different results?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does on the 1st line of code we make implicit boxing?

```
Yes
```

2) Why the 3rd and 6th lines of code give us different results?

`Integer.valueOf(int)` pools all values from -128 to 127.

The reason is that small Integer values are used frequently and there is no point in creating a new object for all such values everytime we need an object. Hence, these are created as **"interned" objects** and all the references to such integer values will **point to the same memory address**.

code snippet from Integer.java:

```
public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    if(i >= -128 && i <= IntegerCache.high)
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + 128];
    else
        return new Integer(i);
}
```

Instead, when you call `new Integer(10);`, it is making an entire new object hence two different objects with same integer values will point to different memory addresses

Comment: So, if I write Integer i1 = 10; compiler impicitly replace it with Integer i1 = Integer.valueOf(10); And it means that if my number in the range from -128 to 127 (or your IntegerCache.high) it gives me already existing object of Integer. And it is the main reason why we get true during the == comparison.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> 1) Does on the 1st line of code we make implicit boxing?
> ```

Yes. Its called [Auto-Boxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)

> ```
> 2) Why the 3rd and 6th lines of code give us different results?
> ```

The == actually checks whether two variables are having exactly same value. Note that a primitive variable contain what you see, but a reference variable contain the address to the object that it holds.

When == is used to compare a primitive to a wrapper, the wrapper will be unwrapped and the comparison will be primitive to primitive, and hence it will be true always as it is a primitive comparison and not object comparison. So that's why

```
System.out.println(i1 == i2);
```

Will be true.

But in line 6.

```
System.out.println(i3 == i4);
```

You are comparing two objects unless the objects have the same reference it will not be true. If you use .equals method you can get true. Try

```
System.out.println(i3.equals(i4));
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, the compiler is using boxing to assign the variables. In this case, i1/i2 are constants (a bit like static final objects).

In the second example, you create two instances of an Integer, hence they are never the same.

Answer (score 0):

The 6 line is showing false because it is comparing to see if the references `i3` and `i4` are pointing to the same object! In this case it is not. hence the `false`.

Autoboxing and UnBoxing comes into picture if there are both wrappers and Primitives involved. Here both `i3` and `i4` are wrapper objects, Hence it will be treated as any other `POJO`

AutoBoxing happens only if there are both wrapper objects and a primitives involved,

for example

```
int primitive = 10;
Integer wrapper = new Integer(10);
System.out.println(primitive == wrapper); //true
```

prints `True` in the above `==` comparison the value of the primitive is compared with the state of the wrapper.

Comment: I understand that it compares two reference. But I don't understand why it do that?