# Java : Equal numbers not matching

Tags: java

I am seeing a strange issue. I have an object, which has a few instance variables, one of which is numeric. This object came out of a socket using ObjectInputStream's readObject(), so it should have been deserialized. However, when i compare it with another object which has the exact same number for that field, using == , it doesn't match. Note: I am not comparing objects, just the integer instance variable, using a getter. Print statements just before the comparison, show that they're exactly the same.

```
    System.out.println("New book id:"+newBook.getId());
for (Book p: listOfBooks) {
    System.out.println("CurrentBook's id:"+p.getId());
    if (newBook.getId() == p.getId()) {
        System.out.println("Matched CurrentBook's id:"+p.getId()) 
            }
    }
```

Thanks Ted Hopp, yes, i guess the behaviour is inconsistent for Integer comparisons with ==. I realised that the fields were Integer, not int, and it worked before, so was very confusing why it no longer worked.

Comment: Please provide code so that we can diagnose.  There's nothing to go off of here

Comment: `==` is just comparing the object's reference with the other. You need implement a `obj1.equals(obj2)` method to compare the internal data.

Comment: Could this be your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149959/using-operator-in-java-to-compare-wrapper-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing numeric objects (`Integer`, etc.) using `==` can give inconsistent results. `Integer`, for instance, will autobox all values between -128 and +127 to cached values, but values outside that range may or may not be cached, depending on the implementation. Thus,

```
Integer.valueOf(-45) == Integer.valueOf(-45)
```

will be `true`, but

```
Integer.valueOf(-145) == Integer.valueOf(-145)
```

will usually be `false`.

For numeric quantities, you should either use `.equals()` or else extract the primitive values (`int`, `long`, etc.) before using `==`

```
num1.intValue() == num2.intValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

readObject() returns an object, so be sure to cast it to an int

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject()

Comment: I cast it to the object that it is, Book, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

> Print statements just before the comparison, show that they're exactly
>   the same.

I think Alex Rellim is right. And the Print statements reads the object's toString method. That's why you see the numbers are the same. If you use a debugger, check the object's type.

Edit (after OP's code's being pasted): Could this be your problem? 
[Using == operator in Java to compare wrapper objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149959/using-operator-in-java-to-compare-wrapper-objects)