# Java Autoboxing through a method

Tags: java, autoboxing, unboxing

Let's say that I have a class:

```
class A {
  private Integer i;

  public int getI() {
    return i;
  }

  // Setter, etc.
}
```

and I write:

```
A a = // initializer

Integer b = a.getI();
```

how many Integers will there be? My naive reading about autoboxing/unboxing leads me to believe that the answer is 2, but if getI() were:

```
public Integer getI();
```

then the answer would be 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are absolutely correct, with one caveat: the answer to the first part depends on the value of `Integer i`.

- In the first scenario, one `Integer` is created in the constructor, and the other one is created when boxing the `int` coming from `getI()`
- In the second scenario, there needs to be no boxing, so there's only one `Integer` object.

Note: if the value of the `Integer i` is small (more precisely, between -128 and 127, inclusive), autoboxing will produce the same `Integer` through [*interning*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10149985/335858).

Comment: Ah, interning too!

A small followup: Is it safer to use the first style? If I use the second style and later make another assignment to b, will a.i remain the same or be updated too?

Comment: @joeblubaugh Both ways are safe: `java.lang.Integer` is *immutable*, so it cannot be updated "behind your back".

Answer (score 1):

Correct....ish

It's theoretically possible the Compiler/JIT/JVM/etc could optimise out the autoboxing but I've no idea if it actually would.

It's also possible the same Integer object would be re-used. For example Integer.valueOf(2) is  guaranteed to give you the same Integer object every time you call it and re-use the same object. This is only guaranteed for values in the range -128 to +127 inclusive though, it may happen outside that range but should not be relied upon.

Comment: Actually it *is* guaranteed between -128 and 127 inclusive. See near the end of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7

Comment: The Java Compiler does not make that much optimisation, because this will reduse the benefit of the JIT.

Comment: Yes, by compiler I meant Just In Time compilation too, could have been clearer.   @Jon that's nice to know - I knew it was the usual case wasn't aware it was required.