# instance variable acts an object , if class is pre-defined

Tags: java

Might be its stupid question!!

Suppose

```
 public class A{

            Long weight = 1200L;  
            Integer i = 10; 
            int z = 20;
            A a;  } 


   public class B extends A{

   public static void main(String[] args) { 

              B b = new B(); 
              B c = new B();
              B d = new B(); 
      }

   }
```

I want to know how many objects are going to be created? 
what i know , 3 objects corresponding to b , c , d and Long , Integer ,int  for each reference. Moreover , each object corresponding to b , c ,d has instance variable "a".

Is this correct? If so , does it mean if i have an instance variables with wrapper class or any pre-defined class , i own object wrt defined class (in mycase Integer and Long)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: By the way, an `int` variable doesn't reference an object.

Comment: int is like A...normal instance variable

Comment: I missed that main was creating instances of B.  9 objects.

Comment: An object is created when you use the object creator keyword `new`, so in this case you have 3 objects. As for `Long` and `Integer` they are just wrapper classes for `int` and `long` respectively. Unless you create an integer like this `Integer i = new Integer(10);`, `i` just holds a primitive variable.

Comment: @Omoro: an Integer is an Integer. It can't be an int. A variable of type Integer references an Object, or doesn't reference anything (null).

Comment: @JB Nizet indeed, you are right.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct about the count of `B`s being created. I think the hard part of the question is designed to check if you understand what happens when

1. A field of a primitive type is defined (field `z`)
2. A field of an object type is defined and initialized (fields `weight` and `i`)
3. A field of an object type is defined but not initialized (field `a`)
4. A field is initialized with an object of a wrapped primitive between -128 and +127

The answer is that an object is created only in the second case. Fields of primitive types are not objects, and uninitialized fields are `null`s.

Note that `weight` and `i` are primitives in object wrappers. Numbers between -128 and +127 are special because of [interning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10149985/335858).

Comment: What about the three instances of B themselves?

Comment: @HotLicks Oops, I forgot to write about it. OP got it right, though. Thanks!

Comment: could you explain more   A field of an object type is defined but not initialized (field a)
A field is initialized with an object of a wrapped primitive between -128 and +128

Comment: @user2985842 The first `B` will create an object for `B`, for `weight`, and for `i`. At this point `i` will be interned. We've got three objects so far. The second `B` will create a `B` again, and it will also create `weight`. However, `i` will be pulled from the collection of interned `Integer`s, so that's an extra two objects, not three. The last `B` will also create two more objects - for the same reason. So that's the total of 7 objects. Note that if you change the definition to `int i = 200;`, object count will be 9, not 7.

Comment: @DavidWallace You're right, it's +127, not +128. I fixed the answer, thanks! By the way, when you see an obvious error like that, feel free to edit - I like good edits :-) Thanks!

Comment: This is a really good question.  It's made me think a lot.  Unfortunately, all this thinking is dangerous.  I don't agree with this answer any longer, and I have removed my upvote.  Sorry, dasblinkenlight.  Integer caching is not the same as String interning.  I will post an answer of my own shortly.

Comment: @DavidWallace In the implementation of `Integer` and its `IntegerCache` static inner class the array of interned `Integer`s is created in the static constructor. The static constructor is invoked when the class gets used for the first time. Assuming that no other code exists in the system in addition to OPs, the call to create all the 256 `Integer`s is performed at the time when the `i` of the first object `B` is initialized. That's why I think it is fair to attribute the creation of `Integer(10)` to OP's code.

Comment: Hmm, by that argument, the answer to this question is 263 - the 256 Integers, the Integer[], and the six other objects.  But then, you'd have to count anything else created by the class loader.  Not to mention the class loader itself.  Where do we stop?

Answer (score 0):

Java maintains an internal cache of 256 `Integer` objects, one for every value from -128 to 127.  When an `int` value within this range is autoboxed, an `Integer` object from this cache is used - that is, a new `Integer` is not created.

Therefore, the values assigned to the variables `b.i`, `c.i` and `d.i` by this code are all references to the objects in the internal cache - new `Integer` objects are not created by this code at all.

When this code runs, three `Long` objects are created, for the variables `b.weight`, `c.weight` and `d.weight`.  Three objects of class `B` are created, for the variables `b`, `c` and `d`.  But this code itself does not create objects other than these six.

The answer to this question is six.