# What's wrong with Integer, Java?

Tags: java, integer

```
    public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i=555,j=555;
        System.out.println(i==j); //false
        Integer l=5,n=5;
        System.out.println(l==n); //true
    }
}
```

Why, Java? How is that even possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427416/why-is-true-for-some-integer-objects?rq=1 - Duplicate, except the other way around.

Comment: Same reason why you almost always never compare `Strings` with `==`.

Comment: @DennisMeng There is more to it than that.

Comment: @arshajii I'm probably oversimplifying, but understanding one will help in understanding the other.

Comment: As mentioned by others, you are comparing objects and also you need to understand internals of Java for integers.

Comment: This is a widely answered question, since Java 5 was released almost 10 years.

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing the references of two different `Integer` class instances with the same value, so you must use the `equals` method (as it must be to compare equality between objects):

```
Integer i=555,j=555;
System.out.println(i==j); //false
Integer i=555,j=555;
System.out.println(i.equals(j)); //true
```

But `Integer` has a pool of `Integer` object instances for `int` values between -128 and 127. So when you do

```
Integer l=5,n=5;
System.out.println(l==n); //true
```

You receive `true` since `l` and `n` *points* to the same object reference.